# Spring error con metodo to.string()

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring

Estoy en la práctica de un curso de Spring, en el momento en el que yo quiero utilizar en mi foreach el metodo **to.string()**, para poder mostrar los elementos, me tira el respectivo error que dejo en los logs.
Lo estuve trantando de investigar y veo que puede llegar a tocar el tema de **to.string()** por que me redirije ahí, además también veo algún problema en esta linea, que me llama la atencion:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy.
```

No tengo idea si puede estar todo relacionado pero calculo que si.
Probe sacando el metodo **to.string** con **foreach** y funciona todo correctamente.

```
2023-07-11T23:06:12.074-03:00 ERROR 4880 --- [main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication : Application run failed
    
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:755) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:319) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at com.springsimplepasos.universidad.universidadbackend.UniversidadBackendApplication.main(UniversidadBackendApplication.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
    Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy [com.springsimplepasos.universidad.universidadbackend.modelo.Carrera#8] - no Session
        at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:164) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:310) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor.intercept(ByteBuddyInterceptor.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.proxy.ProxyConfiguration$InterceptorDispatcher.intercept(ProxyConfiguration.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
        at com.springsimplepasos.universidad.universidadbackend.modelo.Carrera$HibernateProxy$2ozGJY4F.toString(Unknown Source) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453) ~[na:na]
        at com.springsimplepasos.universidad.universidadbackend.modelo.Alumno.toString(Alumno.java:37) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:4213) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:173) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:457) ~[na:na]
        at com.springsimplepasos.universidad.universidadbackend.AlumnosComando.run(AlumnosComando.java:53) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:771) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        ... 5 common frames omitted
```

**En esta funcion lo llamo:**

```
Iterable<Persona> personasApe = 
    personaDAO.buscarPersonasPorApellido(alumno_1.get().getApellido());
    
System.out.println(personasApe.toString());
```

Y aca el metodo **to.string()** en la clase tratando mostrar también su **super** (puede llegar a ser de aqui el error?)

```
 @Override
 public String toString() {
     return super.toString() + "Alumno{" + 
                  carrera=" + carrera + '}';
 }
```

Espero alguna ayuda, muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Hola PVL, el método **toString** que nos muesttras, es de la clase **Alumno**?, si es así, podrías mostrarnos la clase de la cual hereda?, ahora que miro bien, veo **return super.toString() + "Alumno{" + 
                  carrera=" + carrera + '}';**... ese **carrera="** va a fallar, debes escribir: **return super.toString() + " Alumno{  carrera = " + carrera + '}';**